# What is the better implementation for this loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I need to implement a loop where I have to ask the user, and then check the validity of the input (in this case it is necessary to print that is an invalid number). What is the better way to implement it?

Our programming professor does not let us use `break`, and `for(;;)` since, as he says, it is a bad practice. Is that correct?

Example 1:

```
int i = 0;

while(i == 0) {
  cout << "...: ";
  cin >> i;

  /*... Loop body ...*/

  if (i == 0)
    cout << "Not a valid number" << endl;
}
```

Example 2:

```
int i = 0;

do {
  cout << "...: ";
  cin >> i;

  /*... Loop body ...*/

  if (i == 0)
    cout << "Not a valid number" << endl;

} while (i == 0) // Better while(true) and use break ?
```

Example 3:

```
int i = 0;

for ( ;; ) {
  cout << "...: ";
  cin >> i;

  /*... Loop body ...*/

  if (i == 0)
    cout << "Not a valid number" << endl;
  else
    break;
}
```

Comment: Breaks aren't a bad practice... But `for(;;)` loops probably are.

Comment: @Shmiddty, `for (;;)` is a shorter, valid alternative to `while (1)` and `while (true)`. Of course infinite loops are definitely an extra bother in these examples.

Comment: I agree.  For this case especially... example 3 is out of the question.

Comment: `for(;;)` is not as clear as `while (true)`. And break should be avoided unless you really need it or the code is cleaner with break.

Comment: @nhahtdh I disagree, `for(;;)` is the clearest infinite loop of all, IMO.

Comment: That said, the second example is probably the most concise solution.

Comment: There is practically no difference between while(true) and for(;;) right?. Then, is there any better way to implement this?

Comment: I'd agree with the `for(;;)` rule - it may be shorter but serves exactly the same purpose as `while(true)` and is by FAR the less common idiom. `break` is valuable in some cases where complex logic would be required otherwise, but should be avoided to force good programming practices on yourself

Comment: @DanielFischer: I would disagree with you when there are actually some code in the loop.

Comment: I would *love* to see your "professor's" `switch()` blocks if he's so anti-`break`. I'm not saying this is gospel, but it is more often-than-not correct. Proffs have brilliant ideas when it comes to algorithms, but easily some of the **worst** coding skills I've ever seen. That said, re:your question, since you're required to have at least one input cycle, I'd go with option2.

Comment: @WhozCraig good call on the reasoning for do...while vs while

Comment: @nhahtdh Why would `while(true) { doWhatever(); if (done) break; }` be any clearer than `for(;;) { doWhatever(); if (done) break; }`?

Comment: @DanielFischer it's only a matter of semantics, both are exactly correct, but one evokes instinctive response due to its similarity to the spoken language. Your opinion, of course, matters most when debating about these things though

Comment: one reason why people use `for(;;)` is because `while(true)` may give compiler warnings

Comment: @AK4749 I don't think either is similar to spoken language. Nobody (except programmers perhaps) says "while true do that". People say "repeat that forever" or something similar.

Comment: @DanielFischer yeah I guess I see your point, i guess even I got caught in the trap of assuming my way was the highway haha from what you're suggesting, i'd think a `do...while(true)` would be the closest then lol

Comment: Personally, I think the loop condition should always be meaningful. `for(;;)` or `while(1)` or `while(true)` don't indicate immediately when the loops should end. They have no semantic value.

Comment: I can only speak for myself, but when coding I don't think in English or any other spoken language. I think in the language in which I'm programming. This is also why I despise the use of C++'s "alternative representations" `and`, `or` etc over the symbols `&&` and `||` that stand out from identifiers. Do I have a mental illness?

Comment: @Shmiddty: If you have a true infinite loop, then there is no possible indication of when the loops should end. :)

Comment: Using `for(;;)` to implement an "infinite loop" has been idiomatic for decades. It's even in the original K&R book. Any `C` or `C++` programmer should immediately understand it and not be confused.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Amen to that. C and C++ are C and C++, not English or Spanish or Hindi.

Comment: `break` and `for` are bad practice?  He probably wants you to use recursion.  Silly professors.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit is there ever any reason for a true infinite loop? There must always be a situation in which a program must exit, right?

Comment: @Shmiddty: Embedded systems, implanted medical devices, safety and security systems, automatic cat food dispensers, etc.

Comment: @Shmiddty: Quite often in the embedded world, that situation is a power cycle.

Answer (score 2):

In your case the second construct (do..while) is the most intuititve for the reader to look at what the code does, and this is important.

The first one isn't so bad, the last one is poor a "for" construct is usually used where there are a limited number of iterations with the limit set in advance. It doesn't have to be, but intuitively that is how a for loop is used.

(Incidentally if the user entered a string that isn't a number you would have to clear the fail flag on cin, but that is not really the question being asked here).

Answer (score 2):

Don't you need to accept zero as an integer? It's good practice to not rely on input numbers having a special meaning.

If the meaning of the loop is to loop infinitely until the task is done there's nothing wrong with clearly saying `while(true)`. I would probably do something more like this (requires C++11): (or use boost lexical_cast)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

int infini_asker(){
  while (true) {
    std::cout << "...: ";
    std::string tmp;
    std::cin >> tmp;
    int i;
    try{
      i=std::stoi(tmp);
    }catch(std::invalid_argument){
      continue;
    }catch(std::out_of_range){
      continue;
    }
    return i;
  } 
}

int main(){
  int num=infini_asker();
  std::cout << " got:" <<num << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A modification of Example 1 looks to be the best form:

```
while(true) {
    cout << "...: ";
    cin >> i;

    /*... other stuff ...*/

    // Do your input validation here:
    // Note that it's much better to whitelist what is
    // acceptable input as opposed to checking all of the
    // possible cases of invalid input
    if (...) { // where .. is the condition for valid input
        break
    } 
}
```

do-while loops should be reserved for special cases where you want to get the point across that the nested logic should be executed at least once. Anything you can do with do-while, you can do with while(...)

for(;;) is less familiar syntax for a lot of programmers (I didn't know what it meant a year ago), whereas while(true) is much more obvious.

Comment: I think you've sort of contradicted yourself here where you state that the "do-while loops...executed at least once" which i agree with 100%. And his problem states that he must ask the user for input and then check for validity. In that case, why did you not choose the do-while idiom?

Comment: @AK4749 That is an interpretation problem. I would interpret it as "Keep prompting for input until user gives correct input". This is consistent with industry practice - I can't cite a study right now, but from experience while(...) loops are used much frequently than do-while(...) even for cmdline-prompts.

Answer (score 0):

They all work. Like Shmiddty says a for(;;) is not a good programming habit. I would do it like example 2, but I am not a professional programmer.

Comment: haha If only you'd seen "professional" code, you'd be more confident of your answer

Comment: @JohanLundberg I...think that would be more of a design requirement rather than strict mathematical adherence, no? I can't tell if you're joking or not

Comment: why would I be? All those suggested solutions requires a magical number, in this case zero.

Comment: @JohanLundberg I just meant this usually comes up in, for example, menu selections, and say 0 was designed to be the exit input. I think he is aware that 0 is a valid number